# c# show selected data

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to show only the data that contains the cardnumber that i have entered in form1. my table looks like this

```
ID      cardNO     type     amount           date
1       1234       W    100.0000    08/03/2012 17:45:09
4       3455       W    100.0000    08/03/2012 22:10:58
5       5454       W    5.0000          09/03/2012 21:36:45ou
```

so if i entered 1234 is would only show data containing that cardNo
for example

```
ID      cardNO     type     amount           date
1       1234       W       100.0000       08/03/2012 17:45:09
```

i am passing the data from form1 with a variable called show2.cardNO

Am not sure how i can achieve this in visual C#

i want to show this in a datagrid

Comment: Could you post the code of your card class, and how you are storing the list of cards?

Comment: I think you should add a bit more context like what data store you are using (SQL?, MongoDB?).  There are many ways to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: What kind of table is it? What is the type of the data it contains and do you set it to the table.

Comment: i am storing this in an a table on sql server

Comment: Joanne, what sort of control are you using to display the information on form1? Can you include some of the code, please?

Comment: here code i am using in form1 this is the login form

Comment: if ((cardNumber == cardnumberDB) && (pin == pinDB))
                {

                    show.accountID = accT;
                    show2.cardNumber = cardnumberDB;
                         
                    Form2 child = new Form2();
                    child.Show();

Comment: in there i am using sqlconnection, dataadapter, dateset, sqlcommand

Comment: You really need to work on your question quality.  Your previous questions have all been pretty vague. There's always people here willing to help, but you get out what you put in!

Comment: sqlCommand1.Connection.Open(); sqlCommand1.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = show2.cardNumber; sqlDataAdapterLog.Fill(logInstance11.Log); dataGridView1.DataMember = show2.cardNumber.ToString(); - this line aint working sqlCommand1.Connection.Close();

Answer (score 0):

The variable name isn't nearly so important as the variable type, and the controls that are used for display.

Whatever the control and type, you need to filter the data into a new variable, and pass that into your control for display.

The following code uses a ListBox (`lbAvailable`) for display, and a textbox (`txtFilter`) for entering a value to filter the ListBox. Make sure to include a reference to LINQ.

```
private int _filterLength = 0;
private List<Object> _originalItems;

private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtFilter.Text.Length < _filterLength)
    {
        // reset DataSource if filter has had chars deleted
        // so we can re-filter on the original mainly for deletions)
        lbAvailable.DataSource = _originalItems;
    }

    _filterLength = txtFilter.Text.Length;

    // only filter if... there is a filter
    if (_filterLength > 0)
    {
        ApplyFilterToAvailable();
    }
}

private void ApplyFilterToAvailable()
{
    var myOtherList = lbAvailable.Items.Cast<Object>().ToList();
    lbAvailable.DataSource = null;

    var filtered = myOtherList.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(txtFilter.Text)).ToList();

    lbAvailable.DataSource = filtered;
}
```

If you need to see more of the surrounding code, the source is available at [custom select control](https://code.google.com/p/winforms-custom-select-control)

You would have to adapt it for whatever controls you are using -- probably a DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is through sql query in your code.
[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The sql likes:

```
select * from your_table where cardNo = show2.cardNO
```

You have to adjust the code above by your real case.

Comment: sqlCommand1.Connection.Open();
            sqlCommand1.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = show2.cardNumber;
            sqlDataAdapterLog.Fill(logInstance11.Log);
            dataGridView1.DataMember = show2.cardNumber.ToString(); - this line aint working
            sqlCommand1.Connection.Close();